# How to change the monotonous outgoing call ringtone

Tags: calls, custom-sounds

You know that annoying beeping you hear when you call someone, waiting them to pick up? I am completely sick of it and want to customise it on my Huawei Android phone. The question is: how do I do that? Thank you

Comment: I very much doubt that's possible at all. Those "beeps" that tell you whether the line is free or busy are not provided by your device, but rather by the carrier AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

It is called "ringback" or ringing tone and unless the far end has setup custom ringback tones with their carrier, you should get the standardized tone based on the country/region you are in, or more accurately the destination you are calling is in.

These "tones" and other sounds in telecommunications are standardized so they can be recognized by equipment that is intended to see (listen for) specific frequencies, combinations of frequencies, or tonal patterns to denote call progress or other events related to the call. They are often replaced in modern devices with digital signalling, but are still standardized for older equipment.

If you want to change YOUR ringback tone, then your carrier must support it and you will have to set it up with them. Otherwise the receiving caller's carrier is in control of what is heard during ringback in most cases. Your device has no control over what ringback is heard or delivered to callers.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringing_tone